# Using Awk how to merge fields between files, F2 of file1 plus last 8char of F2 in file 2

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have two files file1 and file2, I need to replace F1 value of file1 by merging F2 of file1 plus last 8char of F2 in file2

File 1 :

```
123456|AAAAAAA|BBBBBB|CCCCCCC
444444|kkkkkkk|rrrrrr|NNNNNNN
```

File 2:

```
AAAAAAA|DDDDDD12345678
kkkkkkk|987654321aaaaa
```

Expected Output

```
123456|AAAAAAA12345678|BBBBBB|CCCCCCC
444444|kkkkkkk321aaaaa|rrrrrr|NNNNNNN
```

I have tried with Bellow awk function not sure how to fetch last 8 char of F2 from file2

```
# awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{$2=$2a[$2];print}' OFS='|' File2 File1      
123456|AAAAAAADDDDDD12345678|BBBBBB|CCCCCCC
444444|kkkkkkk987654321aaaaa|rrrrrr|NNNNNNN
```

Comment: Try to format this a little better - I don't think it's necessarily a bad question but like this it probably won't get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the last 8 characters of `a[$2]`, you need to use `substr`:

```
substr(a[$2],length(a[$2])-7)
```

The above takes the substring of `a[$2]` starting at position `length(a[$2])-7`.

With that one change, your code produces your desired output:

```
$ awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{$2=$2 substr(a[$2],length(a[$2])-7);print}' OFS='|' File2 File1 
123456|AAAAAAA12345678|BBBBBB|CCCCCCC
444444|kkkkkkk321aaaaa|rrrrrr|NNNNNNN
```

As Ghoti points out in the comments, the more usual awk style is to use `next` so as to avoid the need for the second condition, `NR>FNR`, as follows:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$2=$2 substr(a[$2],length(a[$2])-7);print}' OFS='|' File2 File1
```

When `awk` encounters `next`, it skips the rest of the commands and starts over on the `next` line.

As `awk` programmers often value conciseness over clarity, it is common to see the `print` statement replaced with a `1`:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$2=$2 substr(a[$2],length(a[$2])-7)} 1' OFS='|' File2 File1
```

In this case, `1` is a condition and it always evaluates to true.  Since no command is associated with that condition, the default command is executed which is `print`.

Comment: Note that `substr(a[$2],length(a[$2])-7)` will do; if you exclude the length, it runs to the end of the string, which is a predictable distance in this case.

Comment: @ghoti Very good. That is a nice simplification.  Answer updated.

Comment: One more simplification might be to avoid the second condition: `'NR==FNR{a[$1]=substr($2,length($2)-7);next} {$2=$2 a[$2]} 1'`. The `next` keeps things localized, also allowing you to use the `1` shorthand.